# Using existing Makefile as part of automake project

Tags: automake

Alternatively the question could be "Using Sphinx documentation in an automake project", that's probably of more interest but harder to achieve.

I'm developing a library that uses automake/autoconf and I hae two kinds of documentation, one uses Valadoc to generate API documentation using comments and the other is Sphinx documentation that ends up in readthedocs. The Sphinx documentation is generated along with a Makefile from the command line but I'd like to build it as part of the project if configuration is passed the option *--enable-doc*. There's nothing particularly amazing about the Makefile that's created, but I haven't been able to find an m4 script that generates it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was so obvious it's almost not worth posting the answer. I just had to rename the existing sphinx Makefile to something like Makefile.sphinx and then add an include line to it at the top of the directory Makefile.am.